# How does SQL store column decimal values?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does SQL Server actually **store** all decimal places, or just up to the last significant digit?

i.e. does it store **`1.700`** or **`1.7`**?

When I query in SSMS I get 1.700 in the results, but other apps looking at the DB report 1.7, so I don't know whether the apps are just being tidy or if SSMS is reporting to the column's decimal places.

The data type of the column I'm looking at is `numeric(10.3)`.

Comment: What it stores, and what it displays depends on the datatype you use for that column.

Comment: I've added datatype to my question

Comment: If you want to consistently display a given number of decimal places then the display should be handled in the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numeric(10,3) column will always store data to the 3rd decimal place.

If there are differences in how it displays, those differences are caused by the application used to view the data.

In SSMS, this code:

```
DECLARE @d numeric(10,3) = 1.7

SELECT @d
```

will always produce this result:

```
1.700
```